# Sectorial Laplace operator in $L^p$

Tags: banach-spaces, laplacian

Can anyone tell me why Laplace operator $\Delta$ is sectorial in $L^p(\Omega)$, where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded (any other hypothesis are needed?) and $1<p<+\infty$? (When $p=2$ seems much more easier, but I'm trying to understand that when I'm not working in a Hilbert spaces.)

Thanks!

Comment: If you considerated the first case $u\in C^2_0$ and after, the closure in $L_p$, yes its sectorial and you can also considerate p=1.